# Get row from TableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, custom-controls

I have written next code so far:

```
UITableView *tableView = (UITableView *)iboTableView;

MovieCell *cell = (MovieCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex:iboImageView.tag]];
```

I can't understand why code crashes? I know what type are the cells, know the index, and have iboTableView.

P.S.

In this function all works:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MovieCell *cell = (MovieCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

**EDIT:**

```
-(void)tapDetected:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
UIImageView *iboImageView = sender.view;
UIAlertView *messageAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                             initWithTitle:@"Row Selected" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", iboImageView.tag] delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];

// Display Alert Message
[messageAlert show];
UITableView *tableView = (UITableView *)iboTableView;
NSIndexPath *index = [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex:iboImageView.tag];
MovieCell *cell = (MovieCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex:iboImageView.tag]];
//DemoTableController *controller = [[DemoTableController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
//FPPopoverController *popover = [[FPPopoverController alloc] initWithViewController:controller];
//popover.contentSize = CGSizeMake(150,158);
//[popover presentPopoverFromView:cell.iboPopImage];
}
```

Comment: What error/s you are getting?

Comment: Where you are wrote this code? and check `iboImageView.tag` value?

Comment: If you have no sections, then you can try the indexPathWithIndex: class constructor Otherwise You have to make in indexPath object manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSIndexPath *index = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:iboImageView.tag inSection:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you giving correct indexPath ?

```
NSIndexPath *myIP = [[NSIndexPath alloc] indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0];
```

Comment: Check your NSIndexPath , if must be giving wrong value. Use this method

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  NSIndexPath *index = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:iboImageView.tag inSection:0];
  NSInteger selectedRow = [tableView selectRowAtIndexPath:index animated:YES scrollPosition:nil];
 //MovieCell *cell = (MovieCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

}